# Only do validation for control if another radion button on the page is selected : Only allowed to alter the regular expression

Tags: regex, c#-4.0, validation

I have an entry form that has regular expressions attached to each of the fields in the form.
Each regular expression is updateable.

I have a field that currently has a regular expression    test|tset
which will basicly return true if the field contains one of those words.

Now I should only do this test if a specific radio button on the page is selected.

Please note that i would need to do this in the regular expression.

in logic -
If (CorrectRadioButton is selected)
then the validation should do the  test|tset
else do not do validation

My programming language of choice is c# but this question does not require a codebehind solution.

Can anyone please help with this regular expression ?

Answer (score 0):

Regex in C# cannot check for external conditions: the result of the match is only dependent on the input string.

If you cannot add any other code and you are only able to change the expressions used then it cannot be done.